# In mysql which is the best way to fetch friends data with join statement or In statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, social-networking

In a social networking site we have a scenario like taking news feed of friends against logged in user.

I have a user table, membership table and feed table.
Here membership table is using for friends data.
User table have more than 100K entries and membership take have more than 400K entries.

I have two way to take friends feed...
Either by joining the feed and membership tablle

```
select * from feed join membership on ... where ....
```

Or by IN statement like

```
select * from feed where user_id IN (userids of friends)
```

Here i am facing a loading issue when making a join statement for a newly registered user having a single friend.

So which is the best method for along robust future run ?

Comment: If you want to use data from the `membership`-table you have to use a join. But if not a `IN` is fine to go with.

Comment: Below link will help you for better understand....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query